# Can I get the progress of a Firebase Realtime Database data retrieval?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an RPG in Unity and I am loading the character's design from a Firebase Realtime Database.
However, the retrieval of the JSON I need to load the character happens kinda slowly, so I would like to make some kind of a progressbar instead of just showing the plain designless dummy to the user.
Can I get the progress of the retrieval somehow?

```
void HandleValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args) {
        design = args.Snapshot.Child("availableRooms").Child(currentRoom).Value.ToString();
        if(design != "") {
            Debug.Log("This happens after a few secs only..."); 
            character.LoadFromJson(design); //loading the design here
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Realtime Database APIs don't offer any sort of progress meter.  You would have to be able to break down your single query into multiple queries of a known batch size, and track the progress of the entire batch.